# C++ if else expression error

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

I checked my nested if statements and also closing brackets... not sure why but I get an "expected expression" error while compiling. The error is during this code: `else if (secondCourseEnrollCount >= 20)`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myName, firstCourseID, secondCourseID, thirdCourseID;
    int studentID, firstCourseEnrollCount, secondCourseEnrollCount, thirdCourseEnrollCount;


    firstCourseEnrollCount=secondCourseEnrollCount=20;

    thirdCourseEnrollCount=17;

    cout << "Please Type Your Name: ";

    cin >> myName;

    cout << "Please Type Your Student ID Number without spaces: ";

    cin >> studentID;

    cout << "Please Type Your First Requested Course ID: ";

    cin >> firstCourseID;

    cout << "Please Type Your Second Requested Course ID: ";

    cin >> secondCourseID;

    cout << "Please Type Your Third Requested Course ID: ";

    cin >> thirdCourseID;

    // First If Statement Should Come Here
    if (firstCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
    {
        // True Path Here
        cout << "The first choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;

        cout << firstCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";



        // False Path Here
        // Second If Statement Here
            else if (secondCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
            {
                // True Path Here

                cout << "The second choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;

                cout << secondCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";

                // False Path Here
                // 3rd If Statement Here
                    else if (thirdCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
                    {
                        // True Path Here

                        cout << "The third choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;

                        cout << thirdCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";

                        //False Path Here
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "All Three Courses Have Seats Remaining, " << myName << endl;

                            cout << "You have been enrolled in " << firstCourseID << endl;

                            cout << "You have been enrolled in " << secondCourseID << endl;

                            cout << "You have been enrolled in " << thirdCourseID << endl;
                        }
                    }// End 3rd If Statement

            }// End 2nd If Statement
    }// End 1st If Statement



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have the same number of `{` than `}`...

Comment: `else if` is an extension of `if`, not its content. It's incorrect to write `if (...) { else if(...) { ... }}`. Please check some [basic tutorials](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html) to understand how to use this (and other) construct properly.

Comment: all the comments within this code is my professor indicating where things should go. I'm sorry, I was under the impression that you can have several if else statements NESTED within the if function. That is at least how our professor explained it. This is not homework or a test this is a review. As much as I try to learn if else then statements, it seems to be my weakest point. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is: enroll in course1 if there are <20 students, else try with course2, else try with course3, else nothing to do, sorry.

```
if (firstCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
{
    cout << "The first choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;
    cout << firstCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";

    if (secondCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
    {
        cout << "The second choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;
        cout << secondCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";

        if (thirdCourseEnrollCount >= 20)
        {
            cout << "The third choice currently has 20 Students, " << myName << endl;
            cout << thirdCourseID << " is Already at Maximum Enrollment, so you have not been added to the class";
            cout << "Nothing to do, sorry" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "You have been enrolled in " << thirdCourseID << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "You have been enrolled in " << secondCourseID << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "All Three Courses Have Seats Remaining, " << myName << endl;
    cout << "You have been enrolled in " << firstCourseID << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is a review given to me by my teacher, it's not homework and not a test. However, he specifically wanted a NESTED if else solution. All the comments within the code are his. I simply filled in what he expected me to solve.

Comment: I think I understood what he wanted to do. I'll go ahead and edit the code I posted...

Comment: That makes more sense. I will look further into it and see if that's how he wanted it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The else needs to follow from the if, which you have not terminated with a }

```
if () {

} else if() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do:

```
if (...) {
    ...
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

`else` expresses the alternative path when the condition in `if` is not met, it makes no sense to place it inside this `if`. The only way to define `else` or `else if` is after the scope of `if`:

```
if (...) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of if ... else in C/C++ is

```
if (condition)
  statement1;
else
  statement2;
```

If you want multiple statements, you use brackets

```
if (condition)
{
  statement1;
  statement2;
}
else
  statement3;
```

The statement following an `else` can be another `if`, which is what you are trying to do:

```
if (condition1)
{
  statement1;
  statement2;
}
else
  if (condition2)
  {
    statement3;
    statement4;
  }
```

But the extra level of indentation looks confusing so this is usually formatted as

```
if (condition1)
{
  statement1;
  statement2;
}
else if (condition2)
{
  statement3;
  statement4;
}
```